# Why does increasing byte packets makes the traceroute not map the final destination?

Tags: icmp, traceroute

I'm struggling to understand why increasing byte packets prevent the final destination from responding.

I did

traceroute /*domain_name*/ 1000

and

traceroute -I /*domain_name*/ 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because some link on the path has an MTU (maximum transmission unit) < 1000. The default packet size is 40 IIRC, so its not terribly surprising that at least one link in your path is failing to retransmit your packets when the size jumps from 40 to 1000. See here for more information: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/generic-routing-encapsulation-gre/25885-pmtud-ipfrag.html